# How I append the data of Multiple files into one file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, bash-script

I want to append data of approx 500 files into one file and each of these files are located in their respective dirs.

Also How i can verify the contents of merged file e.g How i verify that data merged have data from all files or does not miss any data from all these file or each file got processed well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cat` with the `>>` operator. Depending upon the directory structure and files location, you can use `ls` or `find` to find the files and in a shell for loop iterate over those files while appending to a target file. For example:

```
for i in $(find /my/path -iname "*.txt")
do
    cat $i >> result.txt
    echo "====$i====" >> result.txt
done
```

In order to verify that you have data from all files, you may insert a temporary pattern at the end of each append to the result.txt file. Later you can `grep` the pattern and verify if all the files were indeed appended. As shown in the above loop, the file `result.txt` should now contain the line `====filename====` for each of the file found. Later you can remove those lines using `sed` as follows:

```
sed /'^===='/d result.txt > tmp && mv tmp result.txt
```

Make sure the pattern you chose is unique otherwise other lines might get deleted with the above sed command.